# AngularJS: use ng-if in choosing a partial template in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, compilation

My directive needs to choose between two partial templates inside its template:

```
<div ng-if="enablerowselection" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection class="grid"></div>

        <div ng-if="!enablerowselection" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

In the linker function for my directive, I get the value for enablerowselection from the attributes:

```
function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
   scope.enablerowselection = attrs.enablerowselection; //enablerowselection is an attribute for my directive
}
```

However, this causes the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign]
```

I guess I need to compile the partial template inside the directive, so I have added the following into the linker function, but it still does not work:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

**Edit:** the following is my directive code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirective);

myDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];

function myDirective($compile) {
   return {
     restrict: 'EA',
     scope: {
        enablerowselection: '='
      },
     templateUrl: '/path/to/directive_tmpl.html',
     link: linkerFn

    };

 function linkerFn(scope, element, attrs) {
     $scope.enablerowselection = attrs.enablerowselection;
     $compile(element.contents())(scope); //does not help
  } //linkerFn
}
```

Comment: could you add code of your directive?

Comment: you might have use isolated scope variable in your directive.

Comment: Could you try using `enablerowselection: '?='` in your isolated scope value by making it optional

Comment: @PankajParkar, that does not seem work, because I got a new error now: Error: [$compile:iscp]

Answer (score 1):

As am seeing that `enablerowselection` as in isolate scope, you should use make that attribute as optional inside your directive, so that if its not provided then directive will not throw an error. You could make that isolated scope attribute by using `=?` against that variable like

```
scope: {
   enablerowselection: '=?'
},
```

And if you needed that value inside your directive then you should add it as attribute inside directive element

```
<my-directive enablerowselection="enablerowselection"></my-directive>
```

Basically you should add scope variable inside that attribute, that will get two way binded as you are using `=`

**Link Function**

```
function linkerFn(scope, element, attrs) {
     //scope.enablerowselection = attrs.enablerowselection; //reomve this
     //you already have value in `$scope.enablerowselection`,
     //you don't need to get it from attribute,
     //'=' in isolated scope means value of parent scope variable specified in attribute,
     //gets available inside the isolated scope(basically its two way binded.)
     $compile(element.contents())(scope); //does not help
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I keep getting the same error: Error: [$compile:nonassign]

Comment: @TonyGW could you add markup where you have `my-directive`?